# How to install studio 19.1o permanently from a Live session

Tags: live-usb, ubuntu-studio, persistence

I am trying to permanently install 19.10 Ubuntu-Studio.  What do you even call that, permanently installing versus the live version where you can't save things  here's a screen shot.

[image]

When I try to run the install Ubuntu Studio 19.10 by clickinig on the icon on the left first a new icon appeared on desktop called 363 GB Volume and now nothing happen when I "run program" from the drop down menu.

Comment: I don't see a screenshot, but I'd avoid using *curse* type language that may be treated as slang by some, but still be offensive to others. I suspect you're talking about a persistent image (over 'live' installer) in your first paragraph but I'm unsure if that's what you mean.  Did you verify your ISO was flawless (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) before writing to media, and after that the image was written correctly (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD refers to any media used, be it cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a situation where you did not heed the warning in the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuStudio):

> A problem has been discovered with the package selection portion of
>   the installer where if one package is unselected then all other
>   packages within the same category (metapackage) get inadvertently
>   uninstalled.

That is currently the only thing which can cause this issue. This issue has been fixed as of Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS.